# What is this scale: (Bb, C#, D, Eb, F#, G, A, Bb)

Tags: theory, scales, terminology, beginner

**I merged Bb major and D major to see what comes up. The scale has the notes: Bb, C#, D, Eb, F#, G, A, Bb.**
What scale is this?
Can I have chords in this scale?
Let me know!

Notation for the scale:
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it is a scale in its own right, other than just a bunch of notes in order? Most scales (minors apart) will have only # *or* b in them. Your header goes to B#, while the body goes to Bb. Spurious..!

Comment: The definition of scale calls for a set scheme to a set of notes.  Cannot any set of notes be written ascending or descending then a scheme be assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant for the scale to go from Bb to Bb and not from Bb to B# (???), it's apparently called the **Ionian ♯2 ♯5** scale.

I found out by going through Wikipedia's category [Musical scales with augmented seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Musical_scales_with_augmented_seconds).
Relevant article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale#Modes).

And, uh, yes, sure you can find chords that will be diatonic with that scale. (That's generally true about pretty much any scale.) Just at a glance I see Bb+, D, Eb or Gmi.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no generally recognised name for this scale other than a simple description like 'Major with #2 and #5'.

Sure, you can build chords from this set of notes.   You can build chords from ANY set of notes. There's even some major and minor triads in there!

Comment: This is not a random scale, as Divizna points, it's a mode of double harmonic scale.

Comment: @user1079505 And yet the article I found doesn't give a name other than "Ionian #2 #5" either, which says exactly the same as "major with #2 and #5".

Comment: If you have to dig deep into the Internet to find a single instance of a label for something, it's a fair indication that that label won't be generally understood.  Stick to the descriptive name.